# Calculate difference or compare two dictionaries - Groundtruth and clustering

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, cluster-analysis

I have two dictionaries h and c. Here 1,2,3 are the folder names and IMG_0001... are all image files contains in each particular folder.

This is my groundtruth

```
h = {'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png'], 
     '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'], 
     '3': ['IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png']}
```

and this is my clustering output images

```
c = {'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png'], 
     '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'], 
     '3': ['IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png', 'IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png']}
```

Now, I have to check and compare two dictionaries and generate an accuracy_score of each folders.
How to write a code in python. There is a cluster evaluation metric - Adjusted Rand Index (ARI) but don't know how should I use it here in comparing groundtruth and clustering dictionaries. Appreciate your help. Thank you so much for your time. I am a beginner in python.

```
import os, pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
h={}
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"folder_paths"):    
    for file in files:
        key, value = os.path.basename(subdir), file  #Get basefolder name & file name
        h.setdefault(key, []).append(value)          #Form DICT
pp.pprint(h)


#####################################

import os, pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
c={}
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"folder_paths"):    
    for file in files:
        key, value = os.path.basename(subdir), file  #Get basefolder name & file name
        c.setdefault(key, []).append(value)          #Form DICT
pp.pprint(c)

#####################################


# diff = {}
# #value = set(h.values()).intersection(set(c.values()))
# value = { k : second_dict[k] for k in set(second_dict) - set(first_dict) }
# print(value)

print("Changes in Ground Truth and Clustering")
import dictdiffer
for diff in list(dictdiffer.diff(h, c)):         
    print(diff)
```

Comment: Hi, can you describe what is it you are trying to achieve? i.e what do you want to be the output of the comparing code? (assuming i don't know what you mean by 'Ground Truth' or 'clustering' in this context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

h = {'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png'],
     '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'],
     '3': ['IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png']}

c = {'1': ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0053.png', 'IMG_0054.png'],
     '2': ['IMG_0020.png', 'IMG_0021.png', 'IMG_0022.png', 'IMG_0023.png'],
     '3': ['IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png', 'IMG_0051.png', 'IMG_0052.png']}

images = []
for key, value in h.items():
    images.extend(value)
print(images)  # ['IMG_0001.png', 'IMG_0002.png', 'IMG_0003.png', 'IMG_0004.png', 'IMG_0051.png', ..., 'IMG_0023.png']

reverse_h = {}
for key, value in h.items():
    for img in value:
        reverse_h[img] = key
print(reverse_h)  # {'IMG_0003.png': '1', 'IMG_0051.png': '3', 'IMG_0004.png': '1', ..., 'IMG_0054.png': '3'}

y_true = [reverse_h[img] for img in images]
print(y_true)  # ['1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2', '2', '2', '2']

reverse_c = {}
for key, value in c.items():
    for img in value:
        reverse_c[img] = key

print(reverse_c)  # {'IMG_0053.png': '1', 'IMG_0020.png': '2', 'IMG_0003.png': '3', ..., 'IMG_0054.png': '1'}

y_pred = [reverse_c[img] for img in images]
print(y_pred)  # ['1', '1', '3', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2']

score = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
print(score)  # 0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: How should I create this y_true and y_pred list in order to get this below
from sklearn import metrics
y_true = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
y_pred = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1]
metrics.adjusted_rand_score(y_true, y_pred) .........Since 2 images are changed in 1st folder and 3rd folder as per above example